# Data Request From Webpage

Tags: php, vb.net

I have an application. On the first window user writes username, password and press enter button. It sends this information to my web site and my Php file looks up the database and echo the expiration date. So my application gets it and decides whether open the application or not.

I have done this data transfer via web browser. I have inserted web browser to my first form and on form load located to my web site. When user press enter button i get data from textboxes and write it to my web site thats on my webbrowser and press the button on my web site with that code

```
    webBrowser1.Document.All("enter").InvokeMember("click")
```

Everything is okey, it works properly but some anti virus programs blocks my application to work.

Is there safer way to send data and get the response?

Comment: You're website should provide an API that can handle this. You should not need a browser for that.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel How can I provide it?